# Unity - Voice SDK does not work on the quest but does on Unity editor

Tags: unity, vr

Estoy haciendo un juego de realidad virtual con Unity y una de las pruebas consiste en decir una frase en un micrófono. Ya que estoy desarrollando el juego para las Meta Quest, estoy usando su propio SDK, Voice SDK, para esto pero hay un problema, funciona en el editor, en Unity, pero no en las Quest una vez compilado el APK, tengo permisos para usar el micrófono así que estoy un poco perdido.

El `GameObject` que hace de botón es este:

[image: Microphone Button]

El script Microfono es así:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "dedo" && !triggerActivated)
    {
        triggerActivated = true;
        appVoice.Activate(GetRequestEvents());
     }
}
// Asignamos los eventos del Voice App Experience
private VoiceServiceRequestEvents GetRequestEvents()
{
    VoiceServiceRequestEvents events = new VoiceServiceRequestEvents();
    events.OnInit.AddListener(OnInit);
    events.OnComplete.AddListener(OnComplete);
    return events;
}
// Cuando pulsamos el botón...
public void OnInit(VoiceServiceRequest request){
    micro.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = false;
    verde.SetActive(true);
    rojo.SetActive(false);
}
// Cuando tenemos una transcripción completa
public void OnComplete(VoiceServiceRequest request){
    triggerActivated = false;
    verde.SetActive(false);
    rojo.SetActive(true);
}
```

El método `OnTriggerEnter` funciona, lo probé poniendo `verde.SetActive(true);` antes de la activación de `appVoice` y se enciende la luz (el objeto verde es una esfera brillante) cuando toco el micrófono con la mano. Lo último es un `GameObject` anidado en este otro que tiene el script `Response Matcher`:

[image: Response]

Alguna idea de porque funciona en el editor pero no en Quest 3? Ni siquiera llega al `OnInit` por lo que supongo que el fallo esta en el `appVoice.activate()`, pero no se que ocurre.

Estoy usando la versión 62 de Meta XR All-in-One SDK y Unity 2022.3.